# Show that if either $X$ or $Y$ is disconnected then $X \times Y$ is disconnected as well

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Here is the statement: *Let $X$ and $Y$ be two non-empty metric spaces. Show that if either $X$ or $Y$ is disconnected, then the Cartesian product $X\times Y$ is also disconnected*

My idea(s): The placement of this exercise in my book is around a section where the connection between connectedness and continuous functions is established, leading me to believe that one could also prove the claim by constructing some function. However, I think that it is also possible to prove it by using the definition of disconnectednessn and choosing an appropriate metric for a product space.

Namely, let $X$ be disconnected and $Z = X \times Y$. Then there exists two non-empty open subsets $S_1, S_2 \subset X$ such that $S_1 \cup S_2 = X$ and $S_1 \cap S_2 = \varnothing$. Since for any $z \in Z: z = (x, y), x \in X = S_1 \cup S_2, y \in Y$ it follows that $\left(S_1 \times Y\right) \cup \left(S_2 \times Y\right) = Z$. Also $\left(S_1 \times Y\right) \cap \left(S_2 \times Y\right) = \varnothing$, as $S_1$ and $S_2$ are disjoint. $\left(S_1 \times Y\right)$ and $\left(S_2 \times Y\right)$.

Now, if we can show that $\left(S_1 \times Y\right)$ and $ \left(S_2 \times Y\right)$ are both open w.r.t. the metric in $Z$, we are done. Thus for $(a, b), (c, d) \in Z$, let $d_{Z}((a, b), (c, d)) = d_{X}(a, c)$. Since $S_1$ and $S_2$ are open w.r.t. $d_{X}$, and the metric does not depend on $Y$, it follows that $\left(S_1 \times Y\right)$ and $\left(S_2 \times Y\right)$ are also open w.r.t. $d_{X}$. Hence there exists two non-empty, disjoint and open subsets of $Z$ whose union is $Z$. Thus $Z$ is disjoint.

Edit: It is a shame that I cannot accept multiple answers, since so far all answers given here have been brilliant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this idea is that $d_Z$ is not a metric unless $Y$ consists of a single point: if $y_0$ and $y_1$ are distinct points of $Y$, and $x\in X$, then

$$d_Z(\langle x,y_0\rangle,\langle x,y_1\rangle)=0$$

even though $\langle x,y_0\rangle\ne\langle x,y_1\rangle$.

However, it is true that $S_1\times Y$ and $S_2\times Y$ are open in $Z$. This is immediate from the definition of the product topology: both are actually basic open sets in the product.

If you’re required to argue in terms of a metric on $X\times Y$, you have to work a little harder, and the argument will depend somewhat on the specific product metric that you use. The most common product metrics define $d_Z(\langle x,y_0\rangle,\langle x,y_1\rangle)$ to be

$$\sqrt{d_X(x_0,x_1)^2+d_Y(y_0,y_1)^2}\,,$$

$$d_X(x_0,x_1)+d_Y(y_0,y_1)\,,$$

or

$$\max\{d_X(x_0,x_1),d_Y(y_0,y_1)\}\,.$$

All of these generate the same topology, so you can use any of them. Let $p=\langle x,y\rangle\in S_1\times Y$. There is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_{d_X}(x,\epsilon)\subseteq S_1$, and for each of these three product metrics it’s straightforward to show that $B_{d_Z}(p,\epsilon)\subseteq S_1\times Y$.

Comment: What is a sufficient argument to show that for one the the listed metrics (since they are topologically equivalent) $B_{d_Z}(p, \epsilon) \subseteq S_1 \times Y$ for a given $\epsilon > 0, p \in S_1 \times Y$? Let $p, p' \in S_1 \times Y, p = (x, y), p' = (x', y')$. If $d_X(x, x') \geq d_Y(y, y')$ then by openness of $S_1$ there exists such $\epsilon > 0$ that $d_Y(y, y') \leq d_X(x, x') < \epsilon$. However, if $d_X(x, x') < d_Y(y, y')$, then ????

Comment: @Qwaster: Just observe that $d_X(x,x')\le d_Z(p,p')$ for all of them.

Comment: I am still having trouble seeing the connection. So as  $d_X(x,x′) ≤ d_Z(p,p′)$, it follows that distances from $x$ to $x', x, x' \in S_1$ are bounded above. How do we go from this to claiming that $B_{d_Z}(p, \epsilon) \subseteq S_1 \times Y$?

Comment: @Qwaster: If $p'\in B(p,\epsilon)$, then $d_X(x,x')\le d_Z(p,p')<\epsilon$, so $x'\in B_{d_X}(x,\epsilon)\subseteq S_1$, and $p'\in S_1\times Y$ no matter what $y'$ is.

Comment: @brian-m-scott Aha! I think I understand. So first construct a ball with radius $\epsilon$ in $S_1 \times Y$. Then show that any element of that ball will satisfy the openness property (with radius $\epsilon$) in such coordinates where the openness is required (in this case solely in $S_1$, but this same procedure could be generalized). And then it follows that $B_{d_Z}(p, \epsilon) \subseteq S_1 \times Y$.

Comment: @Qwaster: Yes, you could describe it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof that uses continuous functions: since $X$ is disconnected, there is a continuous surjection $f:X\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ where the latter is equipped with the discrete topology. Then $g:X\times Y \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ given by $g(x,y)=f(x)$ is a continuous surjection as well (it is equal to $f$ composed with the projection map onto the first coordinate), proving disconnectedness of $X\times Y$.

Comment: A brilliant answer! The same goes for your second suggestion as well. In the end I had to give the credit for Brian M. Scott, as he pointed out how my metric would brake the definition of a metric.

Answer (score 2):

The continuous image of a connected space is connected, so from this the "positive" version of your statement follows:

> If $X \times Y$ is connected then $X$ and $Y$ are connected,

which is logically equivalent to

> $X$ disconnected or $Y$ disconnected implies $X \times Y$ disconnected.

(let $p="X \text{ connected}"$, $q = "Y \text{ connected}"$, $r = "X \times Y\text{ connected}"$ then the first is $$r \implies (p \land q)$$

while the latter is $$(\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \implies \lnot r$$

and simple FOL tells us those are equivalent statements.)

And the first can be seen immediately by noting that $X= \pi_1[X \times Y], Y = \pi_2[X \times Y]$ and applying the "continuous image of connected spaces" fact twice. All we need are that both projections are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is almost correct, except for the justification of openness of $(S_1\times Y)$-- the space $X\times Y$ comes equipped with a very specific topology (the *product topology*) and your task is to show $(S_1\times Y)$ is open in *that particular topology*. (Otherwise, you could just say "let $d_Z$ be the discrete metric, then every set is open hence we are done." There is an obvious problem with the argument.)

The topology on $X\times Y$ can be defined in two ways:

- Either by the definition of product topology, where the open sets in $X\times Y$ are *generated by* (i.e. unions of) the sets in $\{U\times V\;|\; U\overset{\text{open}}\subset X, V\overset{\text{open}}\subset Y\}$. Using this definition, it is immediate that $S_1\times Y$ is open.
- Or by using one of the *product metrics*:

  1. $d_{1}((a,b),(c,d))=d_X(a,c) + d_Y(b,d)$
  2. $d_{2}((a,b),(c,d))=\sqrt{(d_X(a,c))^2 + (d_Y(b,d))^2}$
  3. $d_{\infty}((a,b),(c,d))=\max\{d_X(a,c),d_Y(b,d)\}$

It is a non-trivial fact that all the metrics above induce exactly the product topology on $X\times Y$ so it does not matter which one you choose to prove the openness of $S_1\times Y$-- using $d_\infty$ should be the easiest.